# amazon-product-advertising-api gem + Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ebs

Does the amazon-product-advertsing-api gem work with rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

The gem does not depend on Rails, therefore it would work with any version of any Ruby framework, or on its own. However, it may not work with Ruby 1.9. Since there is no test suite, this is rather hard to determine.

References:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/amazon-product-advertising-api
- http://github.com/completelynovel/amazon-product-advertising-api